# do-release-upgrade failed when migrating Ubuntu 14.04 -> 16.04

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

During do-release-upgrade -d I received the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
 compiz-core : Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.36.2) but it is not installable
               Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
 gvfs-fuse : Depends: gvfs (= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.3) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 is installed
 hplip : Depends: libhpmud0 (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
         Depends: libsane-hpaio (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
         Depends: hplip-data (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
         Depends: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.14.3-0ubuntu3.4) but 3.16.3+repack0-1 is installed
 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libapparmor-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libapt-pkg-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.15) but 2.23-0ubuntu11.2 is installed
 libcairo-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libclone-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libcwidget3 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
 libdbd-mysql-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libdbi-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libebackend-1.2-10 : Depends: libedataserver-1.2-21 (>= 3.17.90) but it is not installed
 libfile-fcntllock-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libglib-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.40.2-0ubuntu1.1) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
 libgtk2-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libhtml-parser-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libio-pty-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 liblist-moreutils-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 liblocale-gettext-perl : PreDepends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-dns-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-libidn-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libnm-gtk0 : Depends: libnm-gtk-common (= 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.5) but 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 is installed
 libnux-4.0-0 : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
 libonline-accounts-client1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libonline-accounts-daemon1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libonline-accounts-qt1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                   Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 liboxideqtquick0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libpam-systemd : Depends: systemd-services (= 204-5ubuntu20.31)
 libpango-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libperl5.18 : Depends: perl-base (= 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.7) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.9 is installed
 libperlio-gzip-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libpurple0 : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libqgsttools-p1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libqofono-qt5-0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                   Recommends: ofono (>= 1.16) but it is not installed
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                     Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5multimedia5-plugins : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libqt5multimediaquick-p5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libqt5multimediawidgets5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libqt5qml5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5quicktest5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                    Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5webkit5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                 Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5widgets5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                  Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libqt5xmlpatterns5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                      Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libsocket6-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.2 but it is not installable
 libstdc++-5-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed
 libstdc++-6-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed
 libstdc++-7-dev : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~14.04~ppa1) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-5-base (= 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) but 5.5.0-12ubuntu1~14.04 is installed
 libsub-identify-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libterm-readkey-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-charwidth-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-iconv-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libtext-soundex-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libubuntu-download-manager-client1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libubuntu-download-manager-common1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                     Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 libudm-common1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 libuuid-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.18.1 but it is not installable
 onboard : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
 pay-ui : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29) but it is not installable or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29) but it is not installable or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29) but it is not installable or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29) but it is not installable
 python3 : Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
           Depends: libpython3-stdlib (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but 3.5.1-3 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
 python3-yaml : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
 qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qt-labs-settings : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qtfeedback : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qtmultimedia : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-qtquick-localstorage : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                                     Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                                   Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-qttest : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-qtwebkit : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-components : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.4.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts-client : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-test : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                          Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-web : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 rhythmbox : Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.3-1ubuntu7 is installed
             Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu2) but 3.3-1ubuntu7 is installed
 rhythmbox-mozilla : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune : Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist : Depends: rhythmbox (>= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depends: python3 (>= 3.5~) but 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
                     Depends: rhythmbox (= 3.3-1ubuntu7) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu2 is installed
 signon-ui-x11 : Depends: libproxy1v5 (>= 0.4.11) but it is not installed
              Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.4.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 thumbnailer-service : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 ubuntu-push-client : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.4.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 unity : Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2) but it is not installable
         Depends: libunity-core-6.0-9 (= 7.2.6+14.04.20160408-0ubuntu1) but 7.4.5+16.04.20190312-0ubuntu1 is installed
 unity-plugin-scopes : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.1) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
 unity-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (< 3.10) but 3.18.2-0ubuntu3.1 is installed
 unity8-private : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                  Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 webapp-container : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                    Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
 webbrowser-app : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.5.0) but 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3 is installed
                  Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
```

I have not be able to resolve the unmet dependencies and am afraid to reboot the server for it might not boot into OS with do-release-upgrade errors.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! How does your `/etc/apt/sources.list` look like? Please [edit] your question to provide the contents. _“am afraid to reboot the server for it might not boot into OS with do-release-upgrade errors.”_ These errors are pre-upgrade checks. If you quit right after getting them (I guess you got a prompt), you should be safe. However, doing a backup before upgrading the OS is always a good thing.

Comment: Since 14.04 is EOL all of the repos have moved.  You might want to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release before upgrading.  The first answer there explains how to do it.

Comment: I think you are wise to avoid reboot. Unfortunately, your mixture of packages suggests that your system may indeed be (or become) unbootable...or may not. Sometimes a situation like this can be repaired; sometimes it cannot. While you have a working system, create an Ubuntu installer and back up your data.